# Power BI Import & Direct Query

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax, powerbi-embedded

I'm looking for a solution to show both the Import & Direct Query data in the same visual within PBI.

The idea is to have data within the last 30 mins provided via the direct query function and data older than 30 mins fed into the visual via direct query. If I'm completely off please do say!

Ultimately the data is coming from one SQL table but is split into two views, > 30 mins ago, <= 30 mins.

I have tried combining within Query Editor & also DAX Union, however, both the times it appears to convert and import the table, then only refreshing the data every 30 mins. Unfortunately, the dataset is rather large, and live visibility is the ultimate goal.

Comment: Did you publish the report? Or are you viewing it in PowerBI Desktop

Comment: The report would be published through powerbi yes.

Comment: Perhaps when published you will be able to view the live functionality? You could test it

Comment: Already tested and found the data was reliant upon refreshing, hence the question!

Comment: Perhaps you are using a direct query without selecting the live connection option?

Comment: Both the import query and direct query work individually (via data gateway), but you cannot get both data sources within the same table to use within one visual?

Comment: did you try to append rows or do a full outer join?

Comment: Append rows. Need to union two tables to use in one set of visuals.